# What strategy to push only a subset of the files in git?

Tags: git, latex, lyx

As an example, I have a directory with three files a *lyx* a *latex* and a *bibtex* file. Both the *lyx* and the *latex* share the *bibtex* file.

I'd like to share with my friends the directory (if possible everything but the *lyx* file).
I use **[overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)** to share latex documents. There I could upload the files directly via `git push origin master`. But, overleaf does not support *lyx* files, so it doesn't allow to push any file.

It would be nice if I could push only part of the directory, but it seems impossible. I thought I could make a branch with only the latex file, but often I have to use all the files at the same time, so it is not convenient this approach.  I read that submodule can be an option, but, in that case, the bibtex file should be separated from the two files, I guess.

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I don't understand much, but note that .lyx files are just plain text files. You could just change the extension from .lyx to .tex if that helps. I'm guessing you're on Windows? On Ubuntu the extension doesn't really mean much.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't explain well. So, the problem is just that overleaf refuses the upload of files with extensions different from tex bib and some pictures. I could rename the lyx file in tex, then it would be uploaded, but it is a bit to tricky as a solution. I'd rather prefer to keep the file extension coherent.

Comment: I see. Changing the extension might be the only way. Maybe contact Overfleaf's support.

Comment: Renate the lyx file to currentname_lyx.tex just for the sake of archiving and sharing it online. A symbolic link (and the answer below suggesting the .gitignore entry) should then set you up.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the .lyx file to a .gitignore file? This will tell git to ignore the .lyx file when pushing to your repository, without you needing to take the lyx file out of the directory. When doing `git push`, you will upload just the latex and bibtex files.